# Update map tiles in Leaflet only when map panning ends?

Tags: leaflet, pan

Currently when the map is dragged a few hundred API requests are sent due to many layers.

I would like the requests to only be sent when the map comes to a stop.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Can you tell a bit more about those requests?

Comment: @TomazicM Sure, The requests are just the standard WMS requests which are sent to request the sounding tiles of the bounding box / tile location. Currently they are sent automatically when the map is moved. I would like them to only be sent when the user has stopped moving the map.

Does that help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution is hiding amongst the options for generic `L.gridLayer`, which then also apply to `L.tileLayer.wms` layer, since it is extension of generic grid layer.

Option is `updateWhenIdle`. Description of the option in docs says:

> Load new tiles only when panning ends. true by default on mobile
>   browsers, in order to avoid too many requests and keep smooth
>   navigation. false otherwise in order to display new tiles during
>   panning, since it is easy to pan outside the keepBuffer option in
>   desktop browsers.

So all you have to do is add this option to WMS layer creation:

```
updateWhenIdle: true
```